# unprivileged_userns_apparmor_policy - what does it do?

Tags: apparmor, sandbox

I am developing some AppArmor profiles, and came across the kernel flag `unprivileged_userns_apparmor_policy`, but I cannot find any documentation about it.  Does anyone know what it does?  I wonder if it might be helpful to me because I am writing AppArmor policies for apps that can use unprivileged user namespaces and I don't want those apps to be able to use a mount namespace to get around the AppArmor profile's file permission restrictions.